# Formalizing the idea of this "equivalence of data" in the category of vector spaces, and how does this generalize to other categories?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

My category theory is almost nonexistent, but this seems like a "categorical idea". So I'm looking to formalize this idea: Given the data of $U,V,W$ vector spaces the following are "equivalent"

$$B:U\to Hom(V,W)$$
where $B$ is a linear map and
$$B:U\times V \to W$$

where $B$ is a bilinear map. Assuming the top, we can define our bottom map as
$$(u,v)\mapsto B(u)(v)$$
and this is linear in $U$ since $B$ up top is a linear map, and linear in $V$ since $B(u)(-)$ is a linear map. Now assuming the bottom, we can just "freeze" the V component. So fix arbitrary $v\in V$, then
$$B:U\to Hom(V,W)$$
$$u\mapsto B((u,v))$$

So yeah, how do I formalize this notion? And how far does this idea generalize?

Comment: You need a cartesian closed category: a category that has products and exponentials. The adjointness between products and exponentials (also called currying), I think, is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks! this is what i wanted

Comment: frabala is slightly incorrect. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category

Comment: Have you read about tensor products, and the tensor-hom adjunction?

Comment: About the title: "data" like what you suggest is often encoded as a functor on a category, so more generally, equivalence of data can be seen as a natural isomorphism of functors. Here your data is on the one hand $\hom(U,\hom(V,W))$ and on the other $Bil(U,V;W)$ : that they are equivalent "data" can be seen by the fact that they are isomorphic functors. In this special case, as $Bil(U,V;W) \simeq \hom(U\otimes V, W)$, this natural isomorphism of functors is actually a special case of an adjunction.

Comment: @Joppy I know about tensor products of vector spaces (or modules a bit more generally) but I haven't heard of the word adjunction before. But I've gathered from these responses that I should learn what that word means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\Vec{\operatorname{Vec}}\newcommand\Set{\operatorname{Set}}\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$In the case of vector spaces (or, more generally, modules over a ring $R$) we have an adjunction
$$V\otimes_k-:\Vec_k\rightleftarrows\Vec_k:\Hom_k(V,-)$$
Thus for every vector spaces $U,W$ we have an isomorphism
$$\Hom_k(V\otimes_kU,W)\cong\Hom_k(U,\Hom_k(V,W))$$
which formalize the corrispondece you give in the OP.

A similar adjunction holds, for example in category of sets, with the adjunction
$$V\times-:\Set\rightleftarrows\Set:(-)^V$$
which gives for every set $U,W$ a bijection
$$\Hom(V\times U,W)\cong\Hom(U,W^V)$$
which can be written as
$$W^{V\times U}\cong (W^V)^U$$